# writeValue not called Angular custom form control

Tags: angular, controlvalueaccessor

I have several custom form control components in my app so I've implemented a base component that implements the `ControlValueAccessor`.

```js
export class BaseControlValueAccessor<T> implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
    @Input()
    disabled: boolean;

    @Input()
    required = false;

    @Input()
    label = '';

    @Input()
    name = '';

    @Input()
    placeholder = '';

    @Input()
    value: T;

    constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) {
        if (ngControl) {
            ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
        }
    }

    public onChange(newVal: T) {}
    public onTouched(_?: any) {}

    public writeValue(obj: T) {
        this.value = obj;
        console.log(obj); // <------------ 
    }

    public registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    public registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }

    public setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean) {
        this.disabled = isDisabled;
    }
}
```

And all of my custom form controls extend this base class. It's all good until here.

In one of the form controls, I needed to replace the original `writeValue` method. The problem is that the new `writeValue` method is not called but the `writeValue` method in the base class gets called.

```js
export class CustomFormControl extends BaseControlValueAccessor<string> {
    constructor(
        @Self() @Optional() private ngControl: NgControl
    ) {
        super(ngControl);
    }

    writeValue(value: string) {
        this.value = value;
        console.log(value); // <- This is not called but the above log is called.
    }
}
```

Did anyone face this issue before? Actually, it seems more related to class inheritance than angular form control, however, I think I've implemented this correctly. Hope to get any help from you.

Comment: for me works, writeValue reemplace the old writeValue, see this stackblitz with your code:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4bzjn3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-form-control.ts (NOTE: I need declare as public the ngCnontrol in your custom form control

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same issue with the same conditions.

In a mystical way found out that apparently **this** in valueAccessor assignment refers actually to the *base* class, which is *decorated*, and as far as I can tell, results in a *separate* compilation, which leads to  a situation, where your derived class gets caught by outer form/control once and further calls go directly to base class.

Moving your assignment **from base** class **into derived** class

```
    if (this.ngControl) this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
```

solves the referencing issue.

Not the best solution, but only one line to explicitly tell other developers, that this actual class provides ControlValueAccessor functionality.